# How do you show labels on a common xaxis with plotly while having a spike line on all subplots

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to stack different graphs vertically that all have a common x axis. When I hover over the graph I would like a spikeline to go through all subplots and ideally have the hover be "unified" and show data for all subplots. But according to the github issues the hover isn't on the roadmap. https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4755

I have the following:

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

reference_distance = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
compare_distance = [0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
reference_time = [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]
reference_speed = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
compare_speed = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250]

delta_t = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]

base = [0] * len(delta_t)

fig = go.Figure()

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=compare_distance,
        y=base,
        name='Reference Delta',
        hoverinfo='skip'
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=compare_distance,
        y=delta_t,
        name='Compare Delta',
        hovertemplate='Delta: %{y}<extra></extra>'
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=reference_distance,
        y=reference_speed,
        name='Reference',
        meta='Reference',
        hovertemplate='<b>%{meta}</b><br>Distance: %{x}<br>Speed: %{y}<extra></extra>'
    ),
    row=2,
    col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=compare_distance,
        y=compare_speed,
        name='Comapre',
        meta='Comapre',
        hovertemplate='<b>%{meta}</b><br>Distance: %{x}<br>Speed: %{y}<extra></extra>'
    ),
    row=2,
    col=1
)

fig.update_traces(mode="lines", xaxis="x")

fig.update_xaxes(
    showspikes=True,
    spikecolor="grey",
    spikesnap="cursor",
    spikemode="across",
    hoverformat="none",
)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Delta (Seconds)", row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Speed (MPH)", row=2, col=1)
fig.update_layout(
    spikedistance=10000,
    hoverdistance=10000,
    hovermode="x unified",
    title="Delta T and Speed",
    xaxis_title="Distance (Miles)",
    legend_title="Runs"
)

fig.show()
```

I couldn't get the spikeline to cover both subplots until I put `xaxis="x"` (`xaxis="x1"` seems to have the same behaviour) in the `update_traces` call. I can't understand what exactly this does from the documentation but it did make spikeline cover all subplots. One downside is it has removed the scale/labelsfrom the x axis and I can't get it back. How do I get the scale/labels while also having `xaxis="x"` or the spikeline covering both plots?

Without `xaxis="x"`:
[image]

With `xaxis="x"`:
[image]

Comment: Do you really want subplots with two rows and one column or do you want to plot the four lines on the same graph with a different y-axis?

Comment: Originally I did the one graph with 4 lines and it had one y axis on the left and one on the right. This meant that all the lines where on top of each other. This isn't what I want as the blue and red compare to each other and green and purple compare to each other. I want them to be separate.

Edit: If I can have one graph but have the different Y axis on top of each other, that would be perfect, I will likely want more than 2 y axis in the future.

Comment: Ah, I see. What about using the text param to label all the values on hover instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is really the only workaround that I can think of at the moment, but there may be something better out there.

We will use the `text` param to set the data on hover

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=compare_distance,
        y=delta_t,
        name='Compare Delta',
        text = text_data, # use text here
        hoverinfo='text' # set hoverinfo to text so that is all that is diplayed
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1
)
```

Since row 2 has two graphs, we need to set one of them to `hoverinfo='skip'` or else the data will be duplicated.

I think I set the correct labels for `z = list(zip(delta_t, reference_distance, reference_speed, compare_distance, compare_speed))`, which looks like

```
[(-1, 0, 100, 0, 50),
 (-2, 1, 200, 1.5, 100),
 (-3, 2, 300, 2.5, 150),
 (-4, 3, 400, 3.5, 200),
 (-5, 4, 500, 4.5, 250)]
```

`text_data` joins the labels with the data above but you may need to double check that I matched everything up correctly.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

reference_distance = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
compare_distance = [0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
reference_time = [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]
reference_speed = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
compare_speed = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250]

# zip the data together that we want to use on hover
z = list(zip(delta_t, reference_distance, reference_speed, compare_distance, compare_speed))
# Create the hover data for all plots
text_data = [f'Delta: {d}<br><br><b>Refernce</b><br>Distance: {rd}<br>Speed: {rs}<br><br><b>Compare</b><br>Distance: {cd}<br>Speed: {cs}' 
             for d, rd, rs, cd, cs in  z]

delta_t = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]

base = [0] * len(delta_t)

fig = go.Figure()

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.05)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=compare_distance,
        y=base,
        name='Reference Delta',
        hoverinfo='skip'
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=compare_distance,
        y=delta_t,
        name='Compare Delta',
        text = text_data, 
        hoverinfo='text'
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=reference_distance,
        y=reference_speed,
        name='Reference',
        meta='Reference',
        text=text_data,
        hoverinfo='text'
        # hovertemplate='<b>%{meta}</b><br>Distance: %{x}<br>Speed: %{y}<extra></extra>'
    ),
    row=2,
    col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=compare_distance,
        y=compare_speed,
        name='Comapre',
        meta='Comapre',
        hoverinfo='skip' # skip this or the data is displayed twice
        # hovertemplate='<b>%{meta}</b><br>Distance: %{x}<br>Speed: %{y}<extra></extra>'
    ),
    row=2,
    col=1
)

fig.update_traces(mode="lines", xaxis="x1")

fig.update_xaxes(
    showspikes=True,
    spikecolor="grey",
    spikesnap="cursor",
    spikemode="across",
    hoverformat="none",
)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Delta (Seconds)", row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Speed (MPH)", row=2, col=1)
fig.update_layout(
    spikedistance=10000,
    hoverdistance=10000,
    hovermode="x unified",
    title="Delta T and Speed",
    xaxis_title="Distance (Miles)",
    legend_title="Runs"
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks for this, I will give it a go tomorrow! Do you have any idea why there is no labels/values along the bottom of the x axis? The same way that the Y has 200 and 400 for example?

Comment: I think the above implementation would only work if all runs had the same values for `x` and also they would need to have the same number of data points as I think it just maps array position from `x` to the array position of text data. You can see in your picture that the distance isn't the same for reference and compare, makes it confusing as the spike line is "pointing" at the x/distance value. I think it is possible to write it so that the values would map correctly but I feel that is what is already going on in the background to make a graph, shame can't get the data to make  nice hovers